# I can't get npm modules to work with require?

Tags: node.js, npm

I see other questions but I can't really find an answer to make it work. So here is:

node 0.6.6
npm 1.1.15
win7 64bit

What I've done:

- Installed **node** "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"
- Installed **npm** extracted to "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"
- run from cmd: **npm install express; // installed successfully** (also installed with -g, global)
- created a folder named **express** in "C:\Users\Totty\node_modules" with some content
- created **my app**:

  var app = require('express').createServer();

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.send('hello world');
  });

  app.listen(3000);
- run my app: **node "D:\Totty\NodeJS\projects\express01"**
- got the error: **Cannot find module 'express'**

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object. (D:\Totty\NodeJS\projects\express01\main.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)

I think I have to "say" to my script/node to look into the "C:\Users\Totty\node_modules" folder but I don't know how...

thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471965/what-will-be-the-difference-in-requiremypackage-js-and-requiremypackage/15471995#15471995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing it locally in your app folder:

```
cd D:\Totty\NodeJS\projects\express01
npm install express
```

Comment: ok, I will try. Here at work I've done the same steps but it works, saves data in the users folder and it works with no error. Here I have win vista 32 bit.

Comment: now I think it's always better to put all dependencies in your package.json and then run "npm install" from the project root